# translate behavior and associated model translation

Tags: php, cakephp, translate

I searched the web 1000000000000000 times and i can't find a clean solution for this

this is my CertificateType model translation part:

```
public $actsAs = array('Translate'=>array('title','description')) ;
```

and the Certificate model:

```
public $actsAs=array('Translate'=>array('filename')) ;

    public $belongsTo = array(
    'CertificateType' => array(
        'className' => 'CertificateType',
        'foreignKey' => 'certificate_type_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ) ,
   );
```

But in fetch time the belonged model will not translate:

```
    public function admin_index() {
    $this->Certificate->locale = $this->Session->read('Config.language');
    $this->Certificate->CertificateType->locale =  $this->Session->read('Config.language');
    $this->Certificate->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('certificates', $this->paginate());
    debug($this->Certificate->paginate()) ;
}
```

Why?

Comment: there's some stupid guys just decrease the points which they can't understand!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used this and it is working great!

in AppModel.php I wrote these piece of code:

```
    public function getTranslatedModelField($id = 0, $field) {
    // retrieve active language
    $ActiveLanguageCatalog=CakeSession::read('Config.ActiveLanguageCatalog') ;
    $res = false;
    $translateTable = (isset($this->translateTable))?$this->translateTable:"i18n";

    $db = $this->getDataSource();
    $tmp = $db->fetchAll(
        "SELECT content from {$translateTable} WHERE model = ? AND locale = ? AND foreign_key = ? AND field = ? LIMIT 1",
        array($this->alias, $ActiveLanguageCatalog['locale'], $id, $field)
    );
    if (!empty($tmp)) {
        $res = $tmp[0][$translateTable]['content'];
    }
    return $res;
}   

public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {

    if($primary == false && array_key_exists('Translate', $this->actsAs)) {
        foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
            if (isset($val[$this->name]) && isset($val[$this->name]['id'])) {
                foreach($this->actsAs['Translate'] as $translationfield) {  
                    $results[$key][$this->name][$translationfield] = $this->getTranslatedModelField($val[$this->name]['id'], $translationfield);
                }
            } else if($key == 'id' && is_numeric($val)) {
                foreach($this->actsAs['Translate'] as $translationfield) {  
                    $results[$translationfield] = $this->getTranslatedModelField($val, $translationfield);
                }                   
            }
         }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add code below to AppModel:

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    if(!empty($this->hasMany)) {
        foreach($this->hasMany as $model => $settings) {
            if(isset($this->{$model}->actsAs['Translate'])) {
                if(!empty($results[0][$model])) {
                    foreach($results[0][$model] as $row => $result) {
                        $supplement = $this->{$model}->find('first', array(
                            'conditions' => array(
                                $model .'.id' => $result['id']),
                            'fields' => $this->{$model}->actsAs['Translate'],
                            'recursive' => -1));

                        if(!empty($supplement)) {
                            $results[0][$model][$row] = array_merge($results[0][$model][$row], array_diff($supplement[$model], $result));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(!empty($this->belongsTo)) {
        foreach($this->belongsTo as $model => $settings) {
            if(isset($this->{$model}->actsAs['Translate'])) {
                if(!empty($results[0][$model])) {
                    foreach($results[0][$model] as $row => $result) {
                        $supplement = $this->{$model}->find('first', array(
                            'conditions' => array(
                                $model .'.id' => $result),
                            'fields' => $this->{$model}->actsAs['Translate'],
                            'recursive' => -1));

                        if(!empty($supplement)) {
                            $results[0][$model] = array_merge($results[0][$model], $supplement[$model]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

This works with relation hasMany and belongsTo

Comment: Certificate and CertificateTypes are extends CertificateAppModel.
CertificateAppModel extends AppModel.
All of these makes Certificate Plugin

Comment: $this->Certificate->CertificateType->locale='fr' ;
    debug($this->Certificate->CertificateType->find('all')) ;
without all of others, shouldn't retrieve translated CertificateType?

Comment: I never use plugins in Cake, but this code works good in appModel in 2.4. Clear cache folder tmp/ and try again

Comment: with removing {$model} in " if(isset($this->{$model}->actsAs['Translate'])) { " and expand plugin in main structure it worked! i sent a support ticket for cake team and Mark Story said this issue will not fix in cakePHP 2.x
Warm Regards kicaj

Comment: Show me link to the ticket:)

Comment: https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/4061-translate-behavior-belongsto-association#ticket-4061-2

Comment: Yes, it's not perfect:)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Vahid Alimohamadi for the snipped. I had to modify it to work properly in my proJect.

```
public function getTranslatedModelField($id = 0, $field) {
    // retrieve active language
    //$ActiveLanguageCatalog=CakeSession::read('Config.ActiveLanguageCatalog') ;
    $locale = Configure::read('Config.language');
    $res = false;
    $translateTable = (isset($this->translateTable))?$this->translateTable:"i18n";

    $db = $this->getDataSource();
    $tmp = $db->fetchAll(
        "SELECT content from {$translateTable} WHERE model = ? AND locale = ? AND foreign_key = ? AND field = ? LIMIT 1",
        array($this->alias, $locale/*$ActiveLanguageCatalog['locale']*/, $id, $field)
        );
    if (!empty($tmp)) {
        $res = $tmp[0][$translateTable]['content'];
    }
    return $res;
}

public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {

    if($primary == false && array_key_exists('Translate', $this->actsAs)) {
        foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
            if (isset($val[$this->name]) && isset($val[$this->name]['id'])) {
                //HERE ADDED $field => $translationfield AND PASS IT TO THE getTranslatedModelField
                foreach($this->actsAs['Translate'] as $field => $translationfield) {
                    $results[$key][$this->name][$field] = $this->getTranslatedModelField($val[$this->name]['id'], $field);
                }
            } else if($key == 'id' && is_numeric($val)) {
                //HERE ADDED $field => $translationfield AND PASS IT TO THE getTranslatedModelField
                foreach($this->actsAs['Translate'] as $field => $translationfield) {
                    $results[$field] = $this->getTranslatedModelField($val, $field);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had done a change for getting current language and works perfectly with cacke 2.4.3

```
public function getTranslatedModelField($id = 0, $field) {
    // retrieve active language

    $locale = $this->locale ;// gets the current assigned locale

    $res = false;
    $translateTable = (isset($this->translateTable))?$this->translateTable:"i18n";

    $db = $this->getDataSource();
    $tmp = $db->fetchAll(
        "SELECT content from {$translateTable} WHERE model = ? AND locale = ? AND foreign_key = ? AND field = ? LIMIT 1",
        array($this->alias, $locale , $id, $field)
    );
    if (!empty($tmp)) {
        $res = $tmp[0][$translateTable]['content'];
    }
    return $res;
}   

public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {

    if($primary == false && array_key_exists('Translate', $this->actsAs)) {
        foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
            if (isset($val[$this->name]) && isset($val[$this->name]['id'])) {
                foreach($this->actsAs['Translate'] as $translationfield) {  
                    $results[$key][$this->name][$translationfield] = $this->getTranslatedModelField($val[$this->name]['id'], $translationfield);
                }
            } else if($key == 'id' && is_numeric($val)) {
                foreach($this->actsAs['Translate'] as $translationfield) {  
                    $results[$translationfield] = $this->getTranslatedModelField($val, $translationfield);
                }                   
            }
         }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some update to working in cakephp 2.5. It working for me now. Hope can help.

public function getTranslatedModelField($id = 0, $field) {

```
    $res = false;
    $translateTable = (isset($this->translateTable))?$this->translateTable:"i18n";

    $db = $this->getDataSource();
    $tmp = $db->fetchAll(
        "SELECT content from {$translateTable} WHERE model = ? AND locale = ? AND foreign_key = ? AND field = ? LIMIT 1",
        array($this->alias, $this->locale , $id, $field)
    );

    if (!empty($tmp)) {
        $res = $tmp[0][$translateTable]['content'];
    }
    return $res;
}

public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {

    if($primary == false && array_key_exists('Translate', $this->actsAs)) {
        foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
            if (isset($val[$this->name]) && isset($val[$this->name]['id'])) {
                foreach($this->actsAs['Translate'] as $k =>  $translationfield) {
                    $results[$key][$this->name][$translationfield] = $this->getTranslatedModelField($val[$this->name]['id'], $k);
                }
            } else if($key == 'id' && is_numeric($val)) {
                foreach($this->actsAs['Translate'] as $k =>  $translationfield) {
                    $results[$translationfield] = $this->getTranslatedModelField($val, $k);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution is the following get the ids of the associated models items and make another search like the following:

```
            $ids = array();
    foreach ($wpage['Widget'] as &$widget):
        $ids[] = $widget['id'];
    endforeach;

    $widgets = $this->Wpage->Widget->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Widget.id' => $ids)
    ));

    $this->set(compact('wpage', 'widgets'));
```

Thanks,
Aris

Answer (score -1):

Enabling Translate behavior for related models is very easy in Cake way, by using Model->SubModel->Behaviors->load(...)

```
$this->Certificate->CertificateType->Behaviors->load(
    'Translate',
     array('title','description')
     );
```

Have a look at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html